# MySQL Php adding <h2> to a text In the Database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to copy from 1 column to another column basically grab column name and put it inside column descrption but stay on top of the description,so far so good everything is working ,i just can't figure out how to put the finished product into h2 e.g

```
name = Best banana
description = The most yellow thing ever

end result
name = Best banana
description = <h2>Best banana</h2> The most yellow thing ever
```

This is my code so far

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET description = if(description is NULL, name, concat(name, description));";
```

i tried  this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET description = if(description is NULL, name, concat('<h2>name</h2>', description));";
```

But this `'<h2>name</h2>'` displays the word name in h2 and not the table any tips on how to do it?

Comment: `... concat('<h2>', name, '</h2>', description) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET description = if(description is NULL, name, concat('<h2>', name, '</h2>', description));";
```

Comment: Well i feel retarded now,i've been trying to do this for about an hour now...thanks for the help